# Compare response category from 2 columns in Excel and identify category change

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 2 columns that have drop down menus with 5 options (character).

```
orange
apple
banana
broccoli
spinach
```

I want to identify when there are changes from one column to another in a shift from fruit to veggie consumption.  For example:

If people picked orange or apple or banana and still pick those in the 2nd column, no change would be calculated, which would be a count of 0.

But IF those people who picked fruit now pick a veggie, or vice versa, then that count would be 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

[image]

You could have a long list of fruits and vegetables, so I put them in a lookup list in column E.  In column F, I entered `1` for fruits and `-1` for vegetables.

Columns A and B are the values you want to compare and the result is in column C.  The formula in C1 is:

```
 =(1 - VLOOKUP(A1,E$1:F$5,2) * VLOOKUP(B1,E$1:F$5,2) ) /2
```

Copy that down the column as needed.  VLOOKUP finds the word in the list and returns the associated `1` or `-1`.  The two lookup values are multiplied together.  If they are both either fruits or vegetables, the multiplication will produce `1`.  If they aren't the same, it will produce `-1`.

Then `(1 - result)`  will produce `0` or `2`, and dividing by `2` gives you what you wanted.